# Autodesk Forge - Can't view Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm developing Forge. When I access the viewer on Chrome on PC, everything is fine. But on the iPhone, everything is black.

[image: shows up fine in Google Chrome; completely black on iPhone]

Comment: Forge Viewer should be supported on iOS devices without any problems. For example, I can open https://forge-basic-app.herokuapp.com on my son's iPhone 6S without problems. Can you try that website as well?

Comment: @PetrBroz Your example so good. I can open it on my iphone. Looks like I was mistaken something in my app. Can you share your code?

Comment: Sure: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-basic-app

Comment: Many thanks @PetrBroz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, Forge Viewer is supported on older iOS versions as well. If you're able to open some of the other Forge apps such as https://forge-basic-app.herokuapp.com on the device, it could be some issue in your app's JavaScript code. It would be helpful to try and remote debug your application to see if there are any console warnings or errors.